# Validity of connection tokens in HTTP "Connection" header

Tags: http, headers

Is there any rule as to what can be sent as a connection token in the HTTP "Connection" header? For example, are non-alphanumeric characters (besides `-`) like `{` or `/` allowed?

Also, is there a list of valid connection tokens in the header, or is it open-ended? For example, are `Keep-Alive`, `Keep-alive`, `keep-alive`, `keepalive`, and even `keel-alive` considered valid - in the sense that as long as the receiving end knows what to do with them, it's allowed? Or would all receiving ends only allow `Keep-Alive` and drop/ignore the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any rule as to what can be sent as a connection token in the HTTP "Connection" header? For example, are non-alphanumeric characters (besides -) like { or / allowed?

Yes, of course there are rules. The syntax of this header in HTTP/1.1 is defined in [RFC 2616 section 14.10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-14.10), later [RFC 7230 section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.1):

```
   The Connection header field's value has the following grammar:

     Connection        = 1#connection-option
     connection-option = token

   Connection options are case-insensitive.
```

where `1#` means [a list of comma-separated elements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#page-15) and the syntax of `token` is defined in [RFC 2616 section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-2.2), later revised in [RFC 7230 section 3.2.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.6):

```
   token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
   separators     = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
                  | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
                  | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
                  | "{" | "}" | SP | HT

   CHAR           = <any US-ASCII character (octets 0 - 127)>
   CTL            = <any US-ASCII control character (octets 0 - 31) and DEL (127)>
   SP             = <US-ASCII SP, space (32)>
   HT             = <US-ASCII HT, horizontal-tab (9)>
```

This means that `/` and `{` are explicitly disallowed as "separators", but many other non-alphanumerics are still allowed; for example, `.` or `&` or `$` are implicitly allowed as they're included in CHAR and not listed as separators.

The revised rules in RFC 7230 use a reference to [RFC 5234 appendix B.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#appendix-B.1) for VCHAR, and make the list of allowed non-alphanumeric characters explicit (although it actually remains exactly the same list as before).

```
   token          = 1*tchar
   tchar          = "!" / "#" / "$" / "%" / "&" / "'" / "*"
                  / "+" / "-" / "." / "^" / "_" / "`" / "|" / "~"
                  / DIGIT / ALPHA
                  ; any VCHAR, except delimiters

(From RFC 5234)

   VCHAR          = %x21-7E
                  ; visible (printing) characters
```

> Also, is there a list of valid connection tokens in the header, or is it open-ended?

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) says: "any comma-separated list of HTTP headers".

According to the HTTP/1.1 RFC, the *primary* purpose of this header is to be open-ended, as it is supposed to list the names of other request headers that are hop-by-hop. The HTTP/1.1 specification also defines some tokens unrelated to header names, such as `close`, but anything that's not recognized as a specific option is to be treated as the name of a hop-by-hop header.

> For example, are Keep-Alive, Keep-alive, keep-alive, keepalive, and even keel-alive considered valid - in the sense that as long as the receiving end knows what to do with them, it's allowed? Or would all receiving ends only allow Keep-Alive and drop/ignore the rest?

The specification says `Connection options are case-insensitive`, which is expected as the connection options primarily reference HTTP header names, which themselves are case-insensitive. This means that the tokens `Keep-alive` and `keep-alive` would be recognized with the same meaning, whereas `keepalive` and `keel-alive` would still be valid tokens in general but reference different HTTP headers.

However, *none* of those tokens need the receiving end to "know what to do with them", because connections in HTTP/1.1 are already persistent by default – only the opposite behavior needs a Connection header with the 'close' token.

Because of that, there is no special definition for the `Keep-Alive` token in HTTP/1.1; it is not a standalone token (like 'close' is) but simply references the Keep-Alive header if one is present. (An older revision of HTTP/1.1, [RFC 2068 section 19.7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-19.7.1), defines the Keep-Alive header for compatibility with the nonstandard HTTP/1.0 extension.)

Comment: Thank you for this very comprehensive answer!